Are there any English dictionaries that include the (new?) word 'go-withs'?
An online word game recently had the words brat, bun, mustard, and sauerkraut listed under the category “bratwurst go-withs”. I’ve never seen this word before, but googling suggests that it’s being used often enough, and frequently in crossword puzzles. Does anyone know of an English dictionary with an entry to explain this word, what it means, and how it’s used?

What country is the game from? I haven't heard this word before; it might be limited to specific dialects.

This is a transformation of a compound modifier into a noun phrase, I guess. The full phrasing would be "bratwurst go-with foods (i.e., foods that "go with" bratwurst)" Leave out "food" and you turn the modifier into a thing itself: "go-withs" -- things that go with something else. Similarly, "go-to" as in "what are your go-to recipes?" can be transformed into "what are your go-tos for cooking?" Pluralizing a preposition to make it a thing itself is a thing in English, apparently, but I haven't found a precise term or citation for this grammatical thing.

@alphabet - The United States. It was in the New York Times game Connections.

@user8356 - I’ve never seen go-with as an adjective, or the phrase go-with foods, have you?

@76987 -- No, but I totally understood it, and there are the similar constructions -- go-tos, how-tos, FAQs, take-withs, carry-outs, and carry-ons, etc.

Fodder for their next get-together?

It's not even in Wiktionary at the moment. Wiktionary has the largest number of headwords among reliable dictionaries of English, and tends to accept protologisms into the lexis as neologisms faster than most others. UD might list it.  // A complication is that the MWV 'go with' has more than one sense, so a 'go-with' might be interpreted differently by different discoverers. Context will often clarify.

@user8356 - For the record, I’ve never heard of take-withs and can’t find it in a dictionary either.

@76987 I've heard it even though it's not in a any dictionary.

It's not in any major dictionary as its own word. An easy way to check this is by searching for the word on Onelook, which searches through multiple dictionaries.
That said, it is in Wiktionary, buried in an example sentence under the entry for Texas toothpicks. ("Serve the chili hot in wide bowls, along with suitable go-withs.) Make of that what you will.

Go-withs is not that new a word; Esquire noted in an early issue (in the 1930s) that it was common enough to hear the term used as a stand-in for hors d'oeuvres:

After at least a Thirty Years' Culinary War the old hors d'oeuvres have come to our country to stay, but not under their own ritzy name.  Not at all. They're much more likely to be called snacks, appetizers, go-withs, do-dabs or dingle-doos.

The article explains that the term included "whets, thumb-bits, one-bites, two-bites, patties, savories, snacks," and other such foods.
But this seems to be describing 'go-befores,' rather than 'eat-alongsides,' which feels like a more intuitive meaning. Indeed, this is the way it's used today. One cookbook takes credit for the word and claims that it refers to "boldly flavored relishes, pestos, flavored butters, vinaigrettes, seasoned salts, and dips [that] are made separately." Another distinguishes go-withs from sauces, but still groups them together.
So there's not really an exact or official definition, but I think you'll be fine if you use it to describe foods that...go with others.
